# Restlet Server not returning proper responses

Tags: http, restlet, restlet-2.0

I have a ServerResource object that is running within a component. Its purpose is to act in many ways like a basic HTTP server. It uses a Representation to acquire a file and return the file's contents to a browser.

The active function for this application is provided below:

```
   public Representation showPage()
   {
     Representation rep = null;

     if(fileName != null)
     {         
        File path = new File("pages/" + fileName);       
        rep = new FileRepresentation(path,MediaType.ALL);
     }

     return(rep);
   }
```

Note that "fileName" is the name of an HTML file (or index.html) which was previously passed in as an attribute. The files that this application serves are all in a subdirectory called "pages" as shown in the code. The idea is that a browser sends an HTTP request for an HTML file, and the server returns that file's contents in the same way that Apache would.

Note also that the restlet application is deployed as a JSE application. I am using Restlet 2.1.

An interesting problem occurs when accessing the application. Sometimes, when the request comes from a Firefox browser, the server simply does not send a response at all. The log output shows the request coming in, but the server sinply does not respond, not even with a 404. The browser waits for a response for a time, then times out.

When using Internet Explorer, sometimes the browser times out due to not receiving a response from the server, but sometimes the server also returns a 304 response. My research into this response indicates that it should not be returned at all -- especially if the HTML files have no- caching tags included.

Is there something in the code that is causing these non- responses??? Is there something missing that is causing the ServerResource object to handle responses so unreliably? Or have I found a bug in Restlet's response mechanisms?

Someone please advise...

Comment: Which version of Restlet Framework are you actually using?

Comment: The precise version is restlet-jse v2.1.0

Comment: Could you try updating to 2.1.1, we have fixed issues with the internal HTTP server that will probably help.

Comment: Jerome: I have upgraded to v2.1.1 and the problems seem to go away in most cases. Unfortunately, the 304 response continues to occur when I try to access files with Javascript code using Internet Explorer. Unfortunately, this causes IE to fail to display the page -- especially since caching is turned off. Does your version do anything special with IE? If it does, can I turn off the special behavior???

Comment: Could you provide more specific details of a request/response that gives 304, including raw headers?

Comment: I presume the full HTTP request from the IE browser will do? If so, I will have to 'sniff' it. Or can I have the Restlet system print it out? How do I do this... ?

Comment: It would be better to have a look from IE's point of view!

Comment: How do  do this? I can do such using Firebug on Firefox, but to my knowledge there are no tools for monitoring IE requests...

Comment: Firebug Lite should work with IE, not sure if network monitoring does work: https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Tools

Comment: I believe I have found part of the problem. IE under circumstances I cannot seem to control sends If-Modified-Since headers to the server. That is why I am seeing 304 responses with my HTML files (and the browser is generating failures). If I clean the cache the page displays, but in subsequent requests that header is sent again. Is there any way from Restlet to suppress this?